# Raspberry Pi won't run script on boot

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

The program will use a barcode scanner to verify weather a coupon is good or not and will flash either a red or green light depending on if the coupon is valid.

The way I want this to work is to turn on the Pi and then immediately be able to scan coupons. All the Pi has to do is begin the program once I turn on the Pi and remain on and that's all. I am using crontab to begin the following program:

```
#Adam Giancola 
#June 5th 2015

#This program will scan a bar code and if it matches a good bar code will         flash a light
#green or red depending on the validity of the coupon.

import sys, select, os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

greenLED = 16
redLED = 12

GPIO.setup(greenLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(redLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.LOW)
goodBarCode = "0827112134023"

try:
    #Flash LED to test if script is running at RPi boot

    GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    while(1):
        userBarCode = input("")

        if userBarCode == goodBarCode:
            GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.HIGH)    
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

        else:
            GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This codes works fine if I run it through the terminal using "sudo python3 ...blah blah blah" , but I have used crontab to start the program at boot and I am getting no feedback from the LEDs. I know my crontab configuration is working because I have run other programs along side and they are working. Why won't the LEDs respond?

Comment: Why don't you create an init.d script to start the process instead of crontab? You will have to use something like screen or fork the process though.

Comment: I suspect you're missing the hashbang that would tell it what interpreter to use. Try `#!/usr/bin/env python` maybe?

Comment: Nathan I add this to py script?

Comment: How about adding it to /etc/rc.local instead of cron ?

Comment: dastaan I did that and I am getting the same result, it starts but there seems to be a problem with my code that doesn't allow the program to keep running.

Comment: @a-cola, it'd be nice to know if this worked for you as it may help others.

Comment: It did end up working when putting it in rc.local, however it does freeze my RPI up as it just waits for keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the barcode scanner is pretending to be a keyboard. When you run it from the console, whatever the barcode scanner outputs will go to your program as it is the one currently reading on stdin for the console.

When you run it in the background, through rc.local, cron, init script or whatever other method, your program will not be on the console, it will be in the background, so it will not "see" what the barcode scanner types into the keyboard.

Probably the best short term solution for you is to enable auto-login on the console (the GUI has to be off) and call your program right after login. [Full explanation here](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html), short version:

Edit /etc/inittab and change the corresponding line to:

```
 1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Edit /home/pi/.bash_profile and add:

```
 sudo python3 bla bla bla
```

Comment: @Cola, it'd be nice to know if this worked for you as it may help others.